# how do we call reshapes in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, tensors, python

What is the notation for reshape operations in tensors, for example in python's numpy `numpy.reshape(array,dimensions)` or `numpy.flatten(array)`

Agreeing the order is important.

Comment: What **is** reshape of operations in tensors exactly?

Comment: It is changing the tensors dimension, for example having an R^mxn matrix can be reshaped into an  R^(m*n) vector.

Comment: The notation $\mathrm{vec}(M)$ is used for the operation of turning a matrix into a vector, which is called [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). This operation interacts in interesting ways with the Kronecker product. One has, for example, $\mathrm{vec}(AXB)=(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reshaping" a matrix doesn't really have much of a mathematical meaning and I have personally never seen such a notion used in a mathematical text. In the library you are referencing (`numpy`) the operations of "reshaping" and "flattening" are tools to make it easier to abstract over the memory being used to represent an `ndarray`: they give you a "$n$-dimensional" view into a sequence of consecutive elements, which you can then treat like a matrix or a tensor.

If you have a legitimate mathematical use for these operations, you would need likely have to invent your own notation. For example, for $n=ab$, you could denote "reshaping" with the map $\mathrm{Reshape}_{a\times b}: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{a \times b}$ given by
$$
\mathrm{Reshape}_{a\times b}(\vec v) = \begin{pmatrix} 
 v_{(0b)+1} & v_{(0b)+2} & \cdots &  v_{(0b)+b}\\
v_{(1b)+1} & v_{(1b)+2} & \cdots &  v_{(1b)+b}\\
v_{(2b)+1} & v_{(2b)+2} & \cdots &  v_{(2b)+b}\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
v_{(a-1)b+1} & v_{(a-1)b+2} & \cdots &  v_{(a-1)b+b}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But this is hardly comprehensible and doesn't have any obvious useful properties that I can see.

Comment: My question is inspired on reshaping for example images, their local properties mostly disappear once they are flattened however some local properties remain depending on how the reshape is done I guess.

Comment: There actually is a vectorization operation that one sees in the literature.  It can be combined with the Kronecker product to achieve interesting effects. See my comment to the original post.